# Как удалить из `forward_list` последний положительный элемент?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как удалить из `forward_list` последний положительный элемент?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void ViewList(forward_list<int> L)
{
    forward_list<int>::iterator a;
    if (L.empty())
    {
        cout << "List is empty!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (a = L.begin(); a != L.end(); a++)
        {
            cout << *a << "  ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    size_t size = 0;
    forward_list<int> L;
    cout << "Enter elements of list or 'stop' to continue: ";
    string e;
    cin >> e;
    while (e != "stop")
    {
        L.push_front(stoi(e));
        size++;
        cin >> e;
    }
    ViewList(L);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: думаю, раз у вас возникла подребность удаление по такому условию, вы ошиблись с выбором контейнера. Вместо `forward_list` возьмите двунаправленный список (`list`) - он гораздо лучше подходит для подобных задач

Comment: Все просто - бегите по списку, нашли положительное - запоминайте. Вот только нужно запоминать итератор на предыдущий элемент. А потом в конце удалять через erase_after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Приношу изинения за невнимательность, первый вариант был для удаления элемента, предшествующего последнему положительному в списке)*

Для удаления элемента из `forward_list` существует функция `.erase_after()`, в которую надо передать итератор.

Функция, решающая вашу задачу, просматривет список и постоянно запоминает  итератор на элемент, предшествующий текущему (проверяемому, что он положительный). При нахождении положительного элемента  итератор на предыдущий запоминается отдельно.

Функция возвращает итератор на удаленный из списка элемент, если положительных элементов нет, то возвращаем итератор `.before_begin()`

```
forward_list<int>::iterator
remove_last_positive (forward_list<int> &lst)
{
  auto ie = lst.before_begin(), // remove after this
    cur = lst.begin(),          // current list element
    ip = ie,                    // any before cur
    irm = ie;                   // element to remove (return it)

  int remfl = 0;                // flag, that positive element is found

  while (cur != lst.end()) {
    if (*cur > 0) {
      remfl = 1;
      ie = ip;
    }
    ip = cur++;
  }

  if (remfl)
     irm = next(ie), lst.erase_after(ie);

  return irm;
}
```

Comment: Это вариант ответ на вопрос, он удаляет последний положительный элемент. Предыдущий (по моей невнимательности) удалял предшествующий последнему положительному (соответственно, он был немного подлиннее)